# Java Client Authentication-Exception

Tags: java, security, authentication, ssl

Iam fairly new in java security and i'm tasked to do client authentication for my web server.

Files i have from Web server are server.jks client.jks, client.p12, client.pem , and somehow i need to authenticate my client to server using client certificate.

I have this code and i need to know if iam missing some information , because this code throws me exception posted below.

System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");

```
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");



InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("client.p12"));
keyStore.load(is,"ccCert".toCharArray());
is.close();
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,"ccCert".toCharArray());

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());


URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8787");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
con.connect();
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

If anyone can give me some tip what's wrong with my code , or what iam missing it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really appreciate If anyone can post me some usefull reference of how to do client authentication and what  should i not miss while doing client authentication.

Comment: try http://localhost:8787 in url

Comment: Can you try opening `https://localhost:8787` in a browser, and check if the cert and chain are good?

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: jrtapsell
i imported certificate to postman(client for building requests to server) and it works , check screen: http://prntscr.com/ghov21

Comment: Sandip Solanki , i opened the url in browser, i imported certificate and yes it works i have just problem to authenticate using java